# PHP: stripping off image tag from content being echoed on page

Tags: php

I'm spooling out some content from the DB and some of these content might have image but I need to just extract only the text content without echoing any image that might be within the content.

**Sample:**

```
   $nws = '<h3>Just text Just text Just text Just text Just text Just text.</h3>

    <p><img alt="" src="/opt_file/images/09062013C-pix1.jpg" style="width: 400px; height: 231px;" /></p>

<img alt="" src="/opt_file/images/another-pix2.png" style="width: 300px; height: 150px;" />

    <p>Just text Just text Just text Just text Just text Just text.</p>

    <p>Just text Just text Just text Just text Just text Just text.</p>

    <p><strong>Sure these are just text.</strong></p>';

    $nws = str_replace( '<img alt="" src="" />', "" , $nws );

    echo $nws;
```

I tried using str_replace to rip off any image tag or images within but it just won't work.

Also, these content and image are dynamic and there are chances a specific might have multiple image.

Really need to fix this and would be very grateful getting help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex,

```
$nws = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "", $nws);
```

Comment: Glad to help you. Please don't forget to accept my answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `strip_tags()` function, example:

```
$text = '<p>Test paragraph.</p><!-- Comment --> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>';
echo strip_tags($text);
```

To strip particular html tag use this function:

```
echo strip_tags($text,'<p>');
```

Comment: OP only wants `<img>` tag to be removed, though